# WebAPI Validation errors and Response code

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, validation, api-design, fluentvalidation

I am stuck in a dilemma and wanted to hear your opinions.

Given the following conditions:

- All Validation Errors must be returned in one response (user input & business logic validation)
- A User Input Validation (e.g. last name must not be empty) that fails should return `400 BadRequest`
- A Business Logic Validation that requires a unique property (e.g. unique phone number) that fails should return `409 Conflict`

So the following errors correspond to `400 BadRequest`

```
"errors": {
    "LastName": [
      "Last Name field is required" // User Input Validation => BadRequest
    ]
}
```

And the following responds with `409 Conflict`

```
"errors" : {
    "PhoneNumber": [
      "Phone Number is already in use" // Business Logic Validation (Uniqueness) => Conflict
    ]
}
```

What should the response code be when there is an overlap? For example:

```
"errors": {
    "LastName": [
      "Last Name field is required" // User Input Validation => BadRequest
    ],
    "PhoneNumber": [
      "Phone Number is already in use" // Business Logic Validation (Uniqueness) => Conflict
    ]
  }
```

Is there a rule for precedence? Should the above return Conflict or BadRequest?

**For Context**

I am using Asp.Net Core with FluentValidation. I know that this is not really a big deal but this is just a thought experiment and not for a legitimate Api.

Comment: both set them as 400 error, then the issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Error precedence is totally up to you to decide. It is always a good practice to exit early when an error occurs. Normally we return error code 400 when validations fail. So better group and categorize your validation exceptions and business logic exceptions.